# Query Building in Elastic - Java

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, query-builder, spring-data-elasticsearch, elk

I have an elastic query that runs perfectly fine in Kibana, and I get the desired results. But when I try to run it through Java by building the Query using QueryBuilders, the API doesn't work and gives the following error.

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/dev_skp_location/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [locationType] is not of nested type","index_uuid":"0nzK09YiRqmu-s9z_Um0SQ","index":"dev_skp_location"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"dev_skp_location","node":"EIOx4chpQF2JDbGeX8Kc9Q","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [locationType] is not of nested type","index_uuid":"0nzK09YiRqmu-s9z_Um0SQ","index":"dev_skp_location","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"[nested] nested object under path [locationType] is not of nested type"}}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:326)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1654)
        

"reason": "action [cluster:monitor/state] is unauthorized for user [skp_dev] with roles [skp_dev], this action is granted by the cluster privileges [read_ccr,transport_client,manage_ccr,monitor,manage,all]"
```

This is my elastic Query which works on Kibana, what I am trying to fetch is locations which have "pur" in their name and have location Type Level of 1.

```
GET dev_skp_location/_search
{
  "query": {
     "bool":{
        "must":[
        {
          "regexp": { "name": ".*pur*"}
        },
        {
          "nested": {
          "path": "locationType",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { 
                  "match": { "locationType.level": "1" } 
                  
                }]
              }
            },
          "score_mode": "avg"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

And this is my Query Builder Query.

```
public Query AutoCompleteLocationQueryBuilder(String locationTerm, String level, Long tenantId){

        QueryBuilder tenantQuery = QueryBuilders
                .matchQuery("tenantId", tenantId);

        String regexExpression = ".*" + locationTerm + "*";
        QueryBuilder regexQuery = QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("name",regexExpression);

        String nestedPath="locationType";
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        MatchQueryBuilder matchQuery =
                QueryBuilders.matchQuery("locationType.level", level);

        NestedQueryBuilder nestedQuery = QueryBuilders
                .nestedQuery(nestedPath, boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQuery), ScoreMode.Avg);

        QueryBuilder finalQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(tenantQuery)
                .must(regexQuery)
                .must(nestedQuery);

        return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(finalQuery)
                .build()
                .setPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10));
    }
```

Can you help me? As in what mistake I am making? Below is the model for Location.

```
public class LocationSearch {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @MultiField(
            mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = { @InnerField(suffix = "keyword", type = FieldType.Keyword) }
    )
    private String locationId;

    @MultiField(
            mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = { @InnerField(suffix = "keyword", type = FieldType.Keyword) }
    )
    private String name;

    @MultiField(
            mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = { @InnerField(suffix = "keyword", type = FieldType.Keyword) }
    )
    private String code;

    @Field(type=FieldType.Nested, name="parentLocation")
    private ParentLocationSearch parentLocation;

    @MultiField(
            mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = { @InnerField(suffix = "keyword", type = FieldType.Keyword) }
    )
    private String tenantId;

    @Field(type=FieldType.Nested, name="locationType")
    private LocationTypeSearch locationType;
}
```

Model for LocationTypeSearch

```
public class LocationTypeSearch {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @MultiField(
            mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text),
            otherFields = { @InnerField(suffix = "keyword", type = FieldType.Keyword) }
    )
    private String name;

    @Field(type=FieldType.Integer)
    private String level;
}
```

Also the index Mapping function

```
    @Override
    public void indexUserToElasticsearch(Long tenantId, User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(ErrorResponses.USER_IS_NULL);
        }

        UserSearch userSearch = new UserSearch();

        userSearch.setUserId(user.getId().toString());
        userSearch.setUserName(user.getUserName());
        userSearch.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        userSearch.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        userSearch.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userSearch.setTenantId(tenantId.toString());

        this.userSearchRepository.save(userSearch);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please put your index mapping ?

Comment: can only second @SagarPatel's comment.

Comment: thinking about it - the mapping should be alright, otherwise KIbana couldn't run this query.

Comment: How does the class for `LocationTypeSearch` look like?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I have added the class for LocationTypeSearch. Can you please look into it?

Comment: @SagarPatel I have added the mapping as well, I believe that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test with an application using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.5 with your classes `LocationSearch` and
`LocationTypeSearch`, just sending a query to see if this fails, not storing any data and checking the results. I
have no problems with that.

I added the `@Document` annotation to the `LocationSearch` class to define the index to use and removed the `parentLocation` as I don't have the class for that:

```java
@Document(indexName = "location-search")
public class LocationSearch {
    // ...
}
```

In the test I call

```java
  operations.indexOps(LocationSearch.class).createWithMapping();
  operations.search(autoCompleteLocationQueryBuilder("pur", "1", 42L), LocationSearch.class);
```

The first call creates the index and writes the index mapping. The index mapping is nothing where you define a
mapping function, the mapping can be created by Spring Data Elasticsearch on a new index with a call like above.
Spring Data Elasticsearch will look at the annotations on the properties (`@Field`, `@MultiField` etc.) and create
the mapping, which in this case is this:

```json
{
  "location-search": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "doc_values": false,
          "index": false,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "code": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "location-id": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "locationType": {
          "properties": {
            "_class": {
              "doc_values": false,
              "index": false,
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "level": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              },
              "type": "text"
            }
          },
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "name": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "tenant-id": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can retrieve this mapping with a call to */<INDEX_NAME>/_mappings*. Notice that the mapping defines the nested
type for the `locationType` field.

The search created by Spring Data Elasticsearch looks like this:

```json
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "tenantId": {
                            "query": 42,
                            "operator": "OR",
                            "prefix_length": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                            "lenient": false,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "regexp": {
                        "name": {
                            "value": ".*pur*",
                            "flags_value": 255,
                            "max_determinized_states": 10000,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "locationType.level": {
                                                "query": "1",
                                                "operator": "OR",
                                                "prefix_length": 0,
                                                "max_expansions": 50,
                                                "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                                                "lenient": false,
                                                "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                                                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                                                "boost": 1.0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "locationType",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false,
                        "score_mode": "avg",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "explain": false
}
```

This is basically the same that you show for your query, it just contains quite some default values sent in the
query that the Elasticsearch client library adds.

But this query does not fail like in your case.

So I think that the mapping for your index does not contain the correct nested definition. Please check what

```json
GET /dev_skp_location/_mappings
```

returns, if the nested field is mapped correctly - this is the index you are accessing from your application as well?.

For more information about the mapping, check [the Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)